# Hyper HTTP2 custom SSLContext Error

Tags: python, ssl, http2, hyper

I am trying to make HTTP2 request to a server(virtual hosted) which gives SSL certificates based on host header value(SNI).

```
    # conn = hyper.HTTP20Connection('http2.akamai.com', port=443, ssl_context=context)
    # conn.request('GET', '/path', headers={'Host': 'www.mywebsite.com'})
```

Hyper-h2 package for Python won't support SNI or disabling cert verification!
https://hyper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#ssl-tls-certificate-verification

One way to disable certs verification is by having custom SSLContext, and stuck in protocol assertion error

Basic code to make HTTP2 call with custom SSLContext:

```
    import ssl
    import hyper

    # Custom SSLCONTEXT for not verifying SSLCertificate and Hostname
    # or need SSLCONTEXT for SNI support
    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
    context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
    context.check_hostname = False
    hyper.tls._context = context

    conn = hyper.HTTP20Connection('http2.akamai.com', port=443, ssl_context=context)
    conn.request('GET', '/')

    print conn.get_response()
```

Error :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "ssl_custom.py", line 32, in <module>
        conn.request('GET', '/')
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hyper/http20/connection.py", line 281, in request
        self.endheaders(message_body=body, final=True, stream_id=stream_id)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hyper/http20/connection.py", line 544, in endheaders
        self.connect()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hyper/http20/connection.py", line 373, in connect
        assert proto in H2_NPN_PROTOCOLS or proto == H2C_PROTOCOL
    AssertionError
```

EDIT/UPDATE: Now that I learnt how to build context properly `init_context()` the problem still persists when request is made to SNI enabled server.

```
ssl_context = init_context()
ssl_context.check_hostname = False
ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_OPTIONAL

headers={'Host': 'www.opentable.com'}
conn = hyper.HTTP20Connection('ev-www.opentable.com.edgekey.net', port=443, ssl_context=ssl_context)
conn.request('GET', '/washington-dc-restaurants', headers=headers)

print conn.get_response()
```

Output:

```
assert proto in H2_NPN_PROTOCOLS or proto == H2C_PROTOCOL
```

Need a way to specify SNI or Curl equivalent --resolve feature in Hyper

Answer (score 1):

When using HTTP/2 over TLS, the client must negotiate the use of HTTP/2 with the server:

> implementations that support HTTP/2 over TLS MUST use protocol
>   negotiation in TLS [TLS-ALPN]

This is done via ALPN (and historically was done with NPN - hence it's appearance in the error message). That means that when the setting up the context, you must advertise that the client supports HTTP/2 in the TLS `ClientHelo` message.

```
context.set_alpn_protocols(['h2'])
```

Comment: Tried, no luck between learnt from hyper devs, proper way to create context is `ssl_context = init_context()` and I am looking for a way to make requests to SNI enabled server.